# easy: iframe inside string

Tags: php, string

I have a code I think is very hard, but I cannot figure out how to solve it.

I need the iframe working, but doesn't find a way to read it as a code instead of text inside the string...

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="mounting">
    <h1>Mounting</h1>
    <?php
    $a = strtolower($title);
    if (strpos($a, 'vw') !== false){
        if (strpos($a, 'brake disc') !== false){ 
            echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QuyfFY4cvww" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: so... it was rendered as a string instead of creating iframe tag? based on *but dosent find a way to read it as a code instead of text inside the string* part.

Comment: The problem is the php clams. I could close the php before iframe, but then it wouldt show just for the strtolower case, would show "always" instead.

Comment: well, basically you wish to echo the `iframe` **if** `$a` contains `'vw'` and `'brake disc'` ? and the code above did not show the `iframe`?

Comment: tried to replace your `iframe` with another string? because it might be something else causing you problem.. anyway, just checked [youtube developer api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) it looks like it need `&origin=your_url` to allow you embed the video.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using PHP with HTML why don't you do something like this,

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="mounting">
    <h1>Mounting</h1>
    <?php
        $title = 'brake disc vw';
        $a = strtolower($title);
        if (strpos($a, 'vw') !== false){
           if (strpos($a, 'brake disc') !== false){ 
        ?>
           <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QuyfFY4cvww" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <?php
           }
        }
        ?>
   </div>
```

Its basically showing HTML based on if condition, if its true it will be shown else not. There is no need to echo it using PHP.

Comment: There's nothing _wrong_ with using `echo` either, though.

Comment: Except that it doesn't solve anything. If the code in the question doesn't work, this won't work either.